# why does the code occur segmentation fault? sometimes it not occur

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I want to replace the space with "%20" in the sentence.
for example:

```
Input:"How are you?"
Output:"How%20are%20you?"
```

and i am successfully make it in short sentence,but when i use 20+ space.
for example:

```
Input:"                    "
Output: segementation falut
```

I hope to find the reason,thank you everyone.
This is my code in C:

```
char* replaceSpace(char* s ) {
    // write code here
    int len = strlen(s);//to mark the length of s
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        
        if(s[i] == 32)
        {
            len = len + 2;
            for(int j = 0; j < len-i-1; j++){
                s[len-j] = s[len-j-2]; 
            }
            s[i] = '%';
            s[i+1] = '2';
            s[i+2] = '0';
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

thank you so much.

Comment: Since you already got your answer, as a note, be careful with `int len = strlen(s)`, `strlen` looks for a null terminator, and if the string that you passed happens to not contain a null terminator, you will be writing to memory that doesn't belong to you. Make sure that the strings that you pass always are null terminated.

Comment: It also helps to extract a [mcve] first, so you have the code causing the error in isolation. Your code doesn't cause a segfault, because it only declares a function. Therefore, without the actual call, it's impossible to tell why things go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically increase the length like that. You are accessing an un-allocated index outside of s, while referencing it,hence resulting in the seg fault.

Comment: @SergeyHu You can dynamically allocate and reallocate your array, or better yet, start with something big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation Fault usually occurs when you try to access the unallocated portion of the memory.

The possible workaround for this problem is that you make a new string and copy all the characters (except space) normally. For each space character you encounter, you replace that with "%20". So the length of the new string would be thrice as many spaces as it contains plus the rest of the characters (if any).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Construct an ADT called String
typedef struct {
  char *str;
  size_t length;
  size_t str_size;
} String;


// Initialize our ADT
String *initStr(void);
// Free the memory allocated for `String`
void destroyStr(String *);
// Get input from `stdin`
String *input(char *);
// Count the total number of given
// character in the string
size_t count(String *, char);
// Replace each spaces in the string
// with its hex value
String *convert(String *);


int main(void)
{
    String *s = input("Input: ");
    s = convert(s);
    printf("Output: %s\n", s->str);
    
    destroyStr(s);
    return 0;
}


String *initStr(void)
{
  String *s = malloc(sizeof(String));
  s->str = malloc(sizeof(char));
  s->str[0] = '\0';
  s->length = 0;
  s->str_size = 1;
  return s;
}


String *input(char *label)
{
  printf("%s", label);
  String *s = initStr();
  
  int c;
  while ((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    // Dynamically allocate string. If the string
    // length is equal to the internal size, allocate
    // twice as of current length.
    if (s->length + 1 == s->str_size) {
      size_t ssize = s->str_size;
      s->str = realloc(
        s->str, 2 * ssize * sizeof(char)
      );
      
      if (s->str == NULL)
        return NULL;
      
      s->str_size = 2 * ssize;
    }
    s->str[s->length++] = c;
  }
  
  s->str[s->length] = '\0';
  return s;
}


void destroyStr(String *s)
{
  free(s->str);
  free(s);
}


size_t count(String *s, char c)
{
  size_t count = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < s->length; ++i)
    if (s->str[i] == c)
      ++count;
  return count;
}


String *convert(String *old_s)
{
  size_t total_spaces = count(old_s, ' ');
  
  // Return the original string if there are
  // no spaces in it
  if (total_spaces == 0)
    return old_s;
  
  // The new string will contain thrice as many characters
  // for each space plus the other characters
  size_t new_s_len = (
    3 * total_spaces + 
    old_s->length - total_spaces
  );
  
  String *new_s = initStr();
  new_s->str = malloc( (new_s_len + 1) * sizeof(char) );
  new_s->str_size = new_s_len + 1;
  
  for (size_t i = 0; i < old_s->length; ++i) {
    if (old_s->str[i] == ' ') {
      new_s->str[new_s->length++] = '%';
      new_s->str[new_s->length++] = '2';
      new_s->str[new_s->length++] = '0';
    }
    else
      new_s->str[new_s->length++] = old_s->str[i];
  }
  
  new_s->str[new_s->length] = '\0';
  destroyStr(old_s);
  return new_s;
}
```

Since C does not have any built-in `String` datatype, we tried to somewhat emulate the datatype using `struct` and character array. We would also have to handle the memory managements ourselves. This might get cumbersome and is generally not so closely related with the actual problem. Therefore I would urge you to move either to C++ or Rust.